# TypeError: k.google.maps.Load is not a function error in gmap

Tags: php, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

Started to convert a html site to php.
In contact page gmap is not showing, its showing the error

> TypeError: k.google.maps.Load is not a function

in http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/5/main.js file , what could be the reason can any one please help

Answer (score 15):

I had this error when by a mistake the Google Map (maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js) was loaded twice.